# Order selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

```
CustID Sequencing Total
2 1 10
4 2 20
3 2 30
4 4 40
5 8 50
```

I hope to select customer that has order amount >= prev order amount, how to achieve that?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: The logic still isn't clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff meaning for each customer id, we find the order sequence just largest than previous one belong to the customer, if the order amount is larger, than that is the result we want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  and the usage of lag and partition by  not allowed here since we want to make it portable to other sql servers like sqlite.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Using the ANSI standard `lag()` function, you can choose all occasions when a value increases:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(amount) over (partition by customer order by order_sequence) as prev_amount
      from t
     ) t
where amount > prev_amount;
```

EDIT:

For the revised question, you can use `first_value()`.  However, I'm not 100% clear on the exact logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(amount) over (partition by customer order by order_sequence desc) as last_amount
      from t
     ) t
where amount > last_amount;
```

Comment: sorry it is last order rather than previous order, and is it possible to make it simple without using lag and partition by?

Answer (score 1):

For versions 2005, 2008:

```
declare @t table(cust int, ord_s int, ord_a int);
insert @t values
(1,1,30), (1,3,40), (2,1,40), (2,6,30), (3,4,15),
(3,7,60),(3,8,50),(4,2,32),(4,5,2),(4,7,4);

with cte as
(
select row_number() over(partition by cust order by ord_s) as rn, *
from @t
)

select c1.cust,
        c1.ord_s,
        c1.ord_a,
        c2.ord_a as prv
from cte as c1 join cte as c2
         on c1.cust = c2.cust and  c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
where c1.ord_a > c2.ord_a;
```

The idea hear is always the same, you should find the previous order, if you cannot use lag, you enumerate orders within every customer and join ajacent orders as above, if you cannot use even row_number, you can search for nearest value inferior of current one like this:

```
select tt1.*
from 
(
select *,
       (select max(t2.ord_s) from @t t2 where t2.cust = t1.cust and t2.ord_s < t1.ord_s) as prv
from @t t1
) tt1 
join @t tt2
    on tt1.cust = tt2.cust and tt1.prv = tt2.ord_s
where tt1.ord_a > tt2.ord_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Temp table(cust int, ord_seq int, ord_amt int);
insert @Temp values
(1,1,30), (1,3,40), (2,1,40), (2,6,30), (3,4,15),
(3,7,60),(3,8,50),(4,2,32),(4,5,2),(4,7,4);

SELECT 
     Seq AS SeqNo
    ,cust AS CustomerID
    ,ord_seq AS OrderSequence
    ,ord_amt AS OrderAmount
FROM (
    SELECT *,CASE WHEN LAGord_amt IS NULL THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END As  LAGord_amt1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Seq
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ord_amt > LAGord_amt
                THEN ord_amt
            ELSE 0
            END Lagval
    FROM (
        SELECT *,LAG(ord_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY cust ORDER BY ord_seq) As LAGord_amt
        FROM @Temp
        ) Dt
    ) Dt2
WHERE Dt2.LAGord_amt1 = 1
    AND Lagval <> 0
```

OutPut

```
    SeqNo   CustomerID  OrderSequence   OrderAmount
    ---------------------------------------------
     2          1           3               40
     6          3           7               60
     10         4           7               4
```